# How do I make my JFrame class my main class?

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe, program-entry-point

I have looked up a few different solutions, but I keep either getting a "Illegal Start of Expression" error or a "class, interface or enum expected" error.

So I just want to make my JFrame class my main class, because currently my project has no main class.

This is what the start of the code looks like:

```
public class HotelGuiForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public   HotelGuiForm() {
    initComponents();


}
```

and when I insert the Main class code, it just gets errors all over.
Anyone able to help me out?

EDIT:

```
public class HotelGuiForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static void main(String[] args);
{
  public   HotelGuiForm() {
    initComponents();


}
//Rest of Code
}
```

This gives me a illegal start of expression on the public HotelGuiForm(), and if I put the public static void main above the public class I get a missing class enum or interface.

Comment: What errors ? What code ? How to know where the error is ?

Comment: That is a good question. I'll update it.

Comment: If the semi colon after main is actually in your code, remove it. Also, you can't have a method declaration inside main, so take it out and put it inside the class at the same level as main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect code format.

1. You can not have a semi colon after you main function, before its body.
2. You can not write class constructor inside main function. You can call it from main.
3. Constructor should be inside the class body not inside main.

Try this.

```
public class HotelGuiForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public   HotelGuiForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HotelGuiForm HGF = new HotelGuiForm();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Tells me the new instance is ignored.

Comment: assign new HotelGuiForm(); to HotelGuiForm class variable, check edit

Comment: Okay I feel mega stupid, but now it just says "Not used", and I don't actually know what to do here either... I feel like I should know all this, but it must just be completely blanking me.

Comment: @MadsRosenmeyer Just started programming ? You are not using a variable that is why its saying its "NOT USED". When you got the Frame you might want to show it or do something with it. When ever you have declared a variable and you are not using it, it will show this warning.

HGF.setVisible(true); will remove that warning.


Anymore questions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Comment: Well, Im kind of new, and kind of really bad, the main problem is that I've never actually had to do anything of this sort before, so I'm not sure how to instantiate a JFrame as a class variable like that.

Thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HotelGuiForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public   HotelGuiForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new HotelGuiForm();
    }    
}
```

Comment: I get told that new instance is ignored.

Comment: @MadsRosenmeyer it's not an error though. I presume that's your IDE just giving you a friendly warning for your information. It's not uncommon in your psvm (public static void main) method to instantiate a root/core class which in itself it not "used" by subsequent statements but via its constructor orchestrates the rest of the application. So notices from your IDE are useful guidance but you'll have to judge each instance to see whether it's deliberate or not.

Comment: The problem has been fixed above by @HarrisMehmood